# Why is XML custom layout attributes from attrs has no effect inside LayoutParams?

Tags: android, xml

I was trying to work on a [CustomLayout](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) and was following the step from the android's page. When I tried to follow the step, I got into problem with **my_layout_position**.

Let say I have **res/values/attrs.xml** file which contains

```
 <resources>   
    <declare-styleable name="mycostume_layout">

        <attr name="my_layout_position" format="enum">
            <enum name="middle" value="0" />
            <enum name="left" value="1" />
            <enum name="right" value="2" />
            <enum name="bottom" value="3"/>
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Then I have **res/layout/myapp_main.xml** and set app:my_layout_position="right" in Button

```
<com.example.App.MyLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res">
    <Button
       android:id="@+id/button1"
       android:layout_width="145dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:my_layout_position="right"
       android:text="@string/Next"
    />

</com.example.App.MyLayout>
```

Then in the file **App/src/com/example/app/MyLayout.java**

```
public static class LayoutParams extends ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams {

     public int gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.START;

     public static final int POSITION_MIDDLE = 0;
     public static final int POSITION_LEFT = 1;
     public static final int POSITION_RIGHT = 2;
     public static final int POSITION_BOTTOM = 3;

     public int position = POSITION_MIDDLE;


     public LayoutParams(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(c, attrs);

     TypedArray a = c.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.mycostume_layout);            
     position = a.getInt(R.styleable.mycostume_layout_my_layout_position,position);

     System.out.println("position = " + position);

     a.recycle();
}
```

But the **position** returns 0. I was hoping the position would be 2 since I placed  app:my_layout_position="right" in myapp_main.xml.

Comment: Did you override "generateLayoutParams"?

Comment: Yes I did .. similar to that of the android example

Comment: Try to create another two constructors
public LayoutParams(int width, int height) {
            super(width, height);
        }

        public LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams source) {
            super(source);
        }

Comment: Yup I have those two too .. I did exactly  similar to the example of http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was in the file **res/layout/myapp_main.xml** where I had to specify where the costume layout is coming from. In my case its in my app so I had to specify **com.example.App** or what ever is **your package name**

```
 (correct)   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.App"
 (wrong)     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res"
```

Now we can use app:my_layout_position.

I was wondering why XML didn't show error in the first place, it might be eclipse (not sure). It would be interesting to know though :)

```
<com.example.App.MyLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.App">
    <Button
       android:id="@+id/button1"
       android:layout_width="145dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:my_layout_position="right"
       android:text="@string/Next"
    />

</com.example.App.MyLayout>
```